# Check for existing substring even when switched positions

Tags: c#, string, list, linq, lambda

I have an input text file like this:

```
Bunny Gigantus -vs- Dog Majors
Bunny Gigantus Corners -vs- Dog Majors Corners
Bunny Gigantus Penalty -vs- Dog Majors Penalty
Duck -vs- Cat
Tiger -vs- Lion
Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
```

I need to produce an output text file that assigns (original id-match id) for these matches so the expected output will be:

```
1: Bunny Gigantus -vs- Dog Majors
1-1: Bunny Gigantus Corners -vs- Dog Majors Corners
1-2: Bunny Gigantus Penalty -vs- Dog Majors Penalty
2: Duck -vs- Cat
3: Tiger -vs- Lion
3-1: Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
```

Since Bunny Gigantus vs Dog Majors play with each other three times that's why they got 1-1 or 1-2 under this format ("the original match id- number of times they have met until now"). I originally thought of having a `Dictionary<int,string>` but finding duplication in the dictionary seems like a weird thing to do.

I implemented sth like a tree structure with Parent class like this

```
public class Parent
{
    public string firstTeamName { get; set; }
    public int firstDigit { get; set; }
    public int secondDigit { get; set; }
    public bool firstAppearance { get; set; }

    public Parent(string _firstTeamName, int _firstDigit)
    {
        firstTeamName = _firstTeamName;
        firstDigit = _firstDigit;
        secondDigit = 1;
        firstAppearance = true;
    }
}
```

Main Code:

```
const string readPath = @"inputPath";
const string writePath = @"outPutpath";
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(readPath);
            List<Match> listOfTeamsAlreadyPlayed = new List<Match>();
            List<Parent> parents = new List<Parent>();


            int firstDigit = 1;

            foreach (string line in lines)
            {
                string firstTeamInMatch = line.Substring(0, line.IndexOf("-vs-")).Replace("Corners", "").Replace("Penalty", "").Trim();
                string secondTeamInMatch = line.Substring(line.IndexOf("-vs-") + 5).Replace("Corners", "").Replace("Penalty", "").Trim();
                if (!parents.Any(x => (x.firstTeamName == firstTeamInMatch && x.secondTeamName == secondTeamInMatch)))
                {
                    parents.Add(new Parent(firstTeamInMatch, secondTeamInMatch, firstDigit));
                    firstDigit++;
                }
                listOfTeamsAlreadyPlayed.Add(new Match(firstTeamInMatch, secondTeamInMatch));

            }
            int index = 0;
            foreach (Match setOfTeams in listOfTeamsAlreadyPlayed)
            {
                Parent parent = parents.Where(o => (o.firstTeamName == setOfTeams.firstTeam && o.secondTeamName == setOfTeams.secondTeam)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (parent.firstAppearance)
                {
                    lines[index] = parent.firstDigit + ":" + lines[index];
                    parent.firstAppearance = false;
                }

                else
                {
                    lines[index] = parent.firstDigit + "-" + parent.secondDigit + ":" + lines[index];
                    parent.secondDigit++;
                }
                index++;
            }
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(writePath, false))
            {
                foreach (string line in lines)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(line);
                }
            }
```

This code allows me to do the job, however, a new requirement came up which is to make sure that even in the input file the names are switched together they are still be recognized as already played.
So if I have an input file like this:

```
Bunny Gigantus -vs- Dog Majors
Bunny Gigantus Corners -vs- Dog Majors Corners
Bunny Gigantus Penalty -vs- Dog Majors Penalty
Duck -vs- Cat
Tiger -vs- Lion
Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
Dog Majors -vs- Bunny Gigantus
Dog Majors Corners -vs- Bunny Gigantus Corners
```

It will recognized that Dog Majors alreay met Bunny Gigantus so the desirable output file should belike this

```
1: Bunny Gigantus -vs- Dog Majors
1-1: Bunny Gigantus Corners -vs- Dog Majors Corners
1-2: Bunny Gigantus Penalty -vs- Dog Majors Penalty
2: Duck -vs- Cat
3: Tiger -vs- Lion
3-1: Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
1: Dog Majors -vs- Bunny Gigantus
1-1: Dog Majors Corners -vs- Bunny Gigantus Corners
```

However, with the code I have until now, it will make a mistake and recognized the switched name match as a new match. So the output file will be like this:

```
1: Bunny Gigantus -vs- Dog Majors
1-1: Bunny Gigantus Corners -vs- Dog Majors Corners
1-2: Bunny Gigantus Penalty -vs- Dog Majors Penalty
2: Duck -vs- Cat
3: Tiger -vs- Lion
3-1: Tiger Corners -vs Lion Corners
4: Dog Majors -vs- Bunny Gigantus
4-1: Dog Majors Corners -vs- Bunny Gigantus Corners
```

What do you suggest I approach this problem?

Comment: When working out if you've already seen a particular team pairing, swap the team names over if A is greater than B. "Dog" is greater than "Bunny" so do the compare on "Bunny vs Dog" (already seen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirements aren't entirely clear, but I'll make what I think are reasonable assumptions.

I see you noticed that your first approach didn't work because it was based entirely on the first team's name. You've updated your code sample, but forgot to include the new code for Parent and Match. I'm going to assume they look something like this:

```
public record Parent(string firstTeamName, string secondTeamName, int firstDigit)
{
    public int secondDigit { get; set; } = 1;
    public bool firstAppearance { get; set; } = true;
}
public record Match(string firstTeam, string secondTeam);
```

You noticed you need to define a `Match` based on the combination of the two teams. And based on the "new requirement" you need it to not matter which team appears first. One really simple way to do that is to order the teams by their name rather than the order they appear in.

```
var teams = line.Split("-vs-", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
    .OrderBy(t => t)
    .ToList();
string firstTeamInMatch = teams[0].Replace("Corners", "").Replace("Penalty", "").Trim();
string secondTeamInMatch = teams[1].Replace("Corners", "").Replace("Penalty", "").Trim();
```

Now, `Dog Majors -vs- Bunny Gigantus` has an ID of `1-3` instead of `4`. But that's still not right, because you really need to keep track of the fact that this is really exactly the same match that you saw before. To do that, each Match has to be aware of the special modifier ("Corners"/"Penalty") associated with its teams, and you'll need to assign a first and second digit to each distinct Match that occurs. There are various ways you could go about that. Here's what I would do:

I'm going to use an object-oriented approach, specifically using the `record`s that are available in C# 9, because they have automatic implementation of equality methods and such. You could do the same thing just using methods that return strings, but this helps me reason about the logic more easily.

```
record Match(Team Team1, Team Team2)
{
    public static Match Parse(string line)
    {
        var teamNames = line.Split("-vs-", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries)
        .OrderBy(s => s)
        .Select(Team.Parse)
        .ToList();
        return new Match(teamNames[0], teamNames[1]);
    }
    public Match Base() => this with
    {
        Team1 = Team1.Base(),
        Team2 = Team2.Base(),
    };
    public bool IsSpecial => Team1.Special != null;
}
record Team(string Name, string? Special)
{
    public static Team Parse(string teamStr) =>
        teamStr.EndsWith("Corners") || teamStr.EndsWith("Penalty")
            ? new Team(teamStr.Substring(0, teamStr.Length - 8), teamStr.Substring(teamStr.Length - 7, 7))
            : new Team(teamStr, null);
    public Team Base() => this with { Special = null };
}
```

As you see, I'm interpreting "Corners" and "Penalty" to be special modifiers to the "Base" match, and assuming that those modifiers will always be the same for both teams in a match, based on the sample input you've given. My "Base" is what you call "Parent": it's just a Match where there are no modifiers, so I've opted to reuse the same `Match` class rather than defining a new one.

Rather than using `for` loops and trying to track the current state of various indexes, I've opted to use LINQ. I find it easier to debug, as I can use a tool like LINQPad to see the results of each new collection I create and check whether that collection looks the way I think it should at that point--much easier than trying to step through loops and keep track of a bunch of variables' values.

```
var matchLines = lines
    .Select(line => new
    {
        original = line,
        match = Match.Parse(line)
    }).ToList();
var matches = matchLines.Select(e => e.match).ToList();
var matchGroups = matches
    .GroupBy(g => g.Base())
    .Select((bg, bgi) => new
    {
        Base = bg.Key,
        BaseIndex = bgi,
        Matches = bg
            .Where(m => m.IsSpecial)
            .Distinct()
            .Select((m, i) => new { Match = m, Index = i })
    }).ToList();
var matchIndexes = matchGroups
    .Select(g => new { Match = g.Base, Index = (g.BaseIndex + 1).ToString()})
    .Concat(
        matchGroups.SelectMany(g => g.Matches, (g, v) => new
        {
            Match = v.Match,
            Index = (g.BaseIndex + 1) + "-" + (v.Index + 1)
        })
    )
    .ToDictionary(e => e.Match, e => e.Index);

var output = matchLines.Select(e => matchIndexes[e.match] + ": " + e.original )
    .ToList();
```

As you can see, I do build a Dictionary like you were originally thinking, but instead of `Dictionary<int, string>` it's a `Dictionary<Match, string>`. That way, when I go back through the matches, I can quickly find the ID string I've determined to use for that particular `Match`.

Comment: thank you for the Christmas gift. Please pardon my late thank you note.